# How do Google Cloud Logging sinks work when exporting to Cloud Storage? What is the exported format?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#log-sinks

Apparently you can create a log sink and export logs to Cloud Storage.

But how does it work? What will be the exported format of those logs? Will I get 1 file per log entry? Will it be like a `.txt` file? What is the exported format?

From the documentation, this is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log format is in JSON, with one entry per line, and follow [this format](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry). Not really clear in the documentation, but you can find [the information here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#gcs_organization)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've found out:

When you select your project's bucket. A folder will be created with the same name as your `logName` (in my case, `logName === admin-logs`. And there will be folders for years, month and days. Like, today is `2021-02-26` and this was the result:

[image]

As per the file, a `json` file will be created. From the file name, I'm guessin the sink export will happen once every hour.